# How to set key expiration value globally for all the keys of Azure Redis Cache using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: azure, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I'm implementing Azure Redis Cache in Asp.net Core MVC 2.1 application. I need to set the default key expiration value for all the keys globally. And also I should be able to override the expiration duration on individual keys.

I know we could set expiration on individual keys using IDatabase.KeyExpire method, but I'm looking for some sort of configuration that applies to all the keys.

Note: I'm using default eviction policy(volatile-lru), no changes made to it.

Comment: I have finally set the expiry on each key using KeyExpireAsync method of IDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, redis does not provide this ability - you'll have to specify automatically expiring keys. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#specify-automatically-expiring-keys).

When we go to the definition of `IDatabase`, we could see the following picture the `KeyExpire` and only specify single key to set expiration other than the `KeyExists` could set an array of key. So you have to **set expiration value for each key**.

[image]

For more details, you could go to this [article](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis/Interfaces/IDatabase.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save by not having to execute the EXPIRE command for each key? If so, the Redis SETEX command which performs the SET and EXPIRE together might help, and you can use a pre-configured expiry value via an extension method / wrapper. StackExchange.Redis uses the SETEX command when using an expiry. For setting an expiry on individual keys, you can use the EXPIRE command.

Answer (score 0):

In StackExchange.Redis, you can set a default expiration time for all keys by using the SetConfig method on the IServer interface.

```
redisServer.ConfigSet("expire", (int)defaultExpiry.TotalSeconds);
```